# Someone who invites other people to another religion

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was wondering if you could let me know how shall I describe someone who tries to convert people to another religion. The only word I know is ["missionary"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/missionary) who attempts to invite people to a specific religion. So I would say something like:

> - He / she is a Christianity / Islam / Judaism  missionary

I need to know how natives would say such a thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These answers are all focusing on particular words without answering the OP's question about grammar.  To address that, you could write

- He is a Christian [missionary/evangelist/proselytizer].
- He [evangelizes/proselytizes] for Christianity.

Notes:

- A *missionary* is someone who proselytizes professionally, and likely moved far from his own home specifically to do so.
- *Proselytizing* can carry a negative connotation.
- The term *evangelist* is often used in contemporary business; for instance, someone may have a job as a "Brand Evangelist," which would mean that they promote a company's product the same way that an evangelist promotes his religion.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. I wonder if you also let me know if it is possible to say: "He is a Muslim / Jewish [missionary/evangelist/proselytizer]."? --- Also: "He [evangelizes/proselytizes] for Islam / Judaism."?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the grammar.  Technically both "evangelism" and "proselytizing" are specific to Christianity, but of course nowadays you can "evangelize for Coca-Cola" so it could be acceptable to use the term informally.  Religions also have their own terms for their own conversion activities that could be used, e.g. "dawah" in Islam, "soul-winning" in certain protestant sects, etc.  It depends on the context.

Comment: Note that "evangelist" is a much more common term today than "proselytizer".

Comment: Well, "evangelist" is more commonly used with a positive connotation.  "Proselytizer" is still used quite often with a negative connotation.

Answer (score 18):

The specific title *evangelist* is often used to refer to one person: John the Evangelist. In modern Christian usage, there's also the problem that one denomination/strand within Christianity is known as *evangelism*, so if you say "He's an evangelist" people might think you mean "He's an evangelical Christian".

A more generic word, which can apply to any religion, is *[proselytize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proselytize)*.

Collins gives

> to convert (someone) from one religious faith to another

However, it also acknowledges that even an unsuccessful attempt to convert someone counts as proselytism:

> If you proselytize, you try to persuade someone to share your beliefs, especially religious or political beliefs.

A person who proselytizes is a *proselytizer*. A newly converted person, by the way, is a *proselyte*.

Comment: Hmm, it's certainly true that "evangelical" has come to refer to a particular strand of Christianity. But I've never heard the word "evangelist" used to refer to members of that strand. They're called "evangelical Christians" or "evangelicals" for short.

Comment: I don't know why @Max deleted his answer citing ***proselytism*** (which I must admit I'm only familiar with as the adjective or abstract noun ***proselyting***, invariably used pejoratively). But noting [the significant shift in usage patterns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+proselyting%2Chis+evangelism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20proselyting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20evangelism%3B%2Cc0), it probably wouldn't be understood by many people anyway. So perhaps it's not the best choice for OP today (but it is *right!* :)

Comment: *Proselytist* is another word for *proselytizer* and which might be a little more neutral in connotation.

Comment: This may well depend on what denomination one belongs to, but if someone in my church said, "the Evangelist" with no context indicating who, I can't imagine that anyone would assume they mean John. The term "John the Evangelist" is used to distinguish the writer of the Gospel of John from John the Baptist and other Johns mentioned in the Bible, but I've never understood it to be a title specifically applied to this one man. Rather, it's a title used to distinguish among several people named John, and is only really meaningful in that context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That decline you show is for an lesser-used variant form of the verb. [Have another look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+proselyting%2Chis+evangelism%2C+his+proselytizing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8). Also, I've seen/heard _proselytizing_ used in secular contexts as well, such as the [PC vs Mac debate](http://fortune.com/2015/02/08/can-apple-still-be-cool-if-its-products-dominate-your-life/) (scroll down to the last paragraph), and even as a byline in [this whiskey blog](http://whiskeyapostle.com/).

Comment: @J.R.♦: I see you're quite right. If I'd been presented with both variants I'd probably have said the shorter form was "incorrect", but at the time of my earlier comment I didn't even notice anything unusual (I wouldn't be likely to use *either* version myself). And glancing through a few of the more recent instances in NGrams, I get the impression my *invariably used pejoratively* wouldn't exactly stand close scrutiny. I'll leave my earlier comment as testament to my ignorance, but I certainly shan't be miffed if you eventually tidy it away along with all the other "peripheral" comments.

Comment: I don't think the phrase "John the Evangelist" is as widely known as you suggest; I've been within Christianity my whole life and never heard the author of the gospel of John described that way. But I do agree that "proselytize" is a good suggestion.

Comment: I'm a college-educated native speaker, and I've never heard of "proselytize".  So just beware, it's not a common word.

Comment: I've also pretty regularly seen/used *proselytizing* (and to a lesser extent *non-proselytizing*) to describe the philosophies of religions towards the recruitment of converts: Christianity and Islam are proselytizing religions, Hinduism and Buddhism generally are not, Judaism definitely is not. Edit to add--I may have seen/used this more often than some folks, because I'm an American who's *not* Christian and therefore have been proselytized far more often than I would prefer.

Comment: If you're making the case that "evangelism" only applies to Christianity, then certainly so does "proselytism," since a "proselyte" was specifically a gentile newly converted to Christianity.

Answer (score 11):

Such a person could be called an **evangelist**...

> [**Evangelism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelism) *is the preaching of the gospel or the practice of giving information about a particular doctrine or set of beliefs to others with the intention of converting others to the Christian faith.*

Although the above Wikipedia definition specifically limits usage to *the **Christian** faith*, it's by no means impossible to refer to an [evangelistic Buddhist](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22evangelistic%20buddhist%22), for example.

Comment: So how do you say that an evangelist inviting someone else from e.g. Islam to Christianity?

Comment: *Evangelize* is also a verb, so you could say that the person *is evangelizing*.

Comment: E.g. can I say: "He is evangelizing to Judaism" OR "He is evangelizing Christianity"? Are these sentences natural?

Comment: @A-friend: You could certainly say *He's an evangelist for Christianity*, but you'd need to know your audience. Although the UK is primarily atheist today, we're mostly quite tolerant of people who believe in an interventionist god. But that tolerance often reduces quite a lot when it comes to people who *try to convert **others*** to their faith (what you believe in your private life is your own concern, but many people see limits on what you should promote to others).

Comment: You can also use evangelist for secular endeavors, like innovation evangelist, or some-shiny-new-tech evangelist. It has connotations that might be tricky though.

Comment: @ColleenV True, but I think that usage is a metaphor from the Christian usage. Use of "evangelist" to describe Christian preachers goes back hundreds of years. Use to describe advocates for a new product is pretty recent.

Comment: @A-friend I think the common wording would be, "He is evangelizing for X", or "he is evangelizing people to X".

Comment: @Jay: I think if you *evangelize* someone that would almost always imply you've successfully persuaded that person to become an evangelist *themselves* (they might already have believed in the same god as you; perhaps they just didn't feel the need to work tirelessly converting other people to the same faith). In that respect it's similar to ***radicalize***, which is *definitely* a "pejorative" term in the context of religion in the UK today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe this is a regional difference. In the U.S., to "evangelize" means to attempt to convert someone to your religion. It doesn't imply that you succeed. No one would blink at a statement like, "He's been evangelizing for 20 years but has never converted anyone." It doesn't indicate that you convince that person to become an evangelist himself, just a believer in your religion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't doubt that "evangelize" has negative connotations to atheists and extreme secularists in the U.S., but to most I think it's a pretty neutral word. But atheists here -- and your comments imply this applies to atheists in the UK also -- often take the view, "You are free to believe anything you like, as long as you agree that only my beliefs may be spoken in public."

Comment: @Jay: On matters like this it's not easy to be subjective. Personally I find it a bit "offensive" that US politicians have to publicly profess Xtianity in order to be electable, and I find it even *more* offensive that so many of them seem to actually *believe* what they say. Which statement itself will probably be considered offensive by may Americans, whereas in the UK it was unremarkable when many commentators expressed revulsion at Tony Blair's claim that it was okay for him to invade Iraq because he believed his god would approve the action. In this respect, there's a big US/UK split.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you mean, "not easy to be objective". Personally I find pandering more offensive than a sincere belief in an idea I oppose. But yes, I agree that it's certainly true that the UK has fallen far behind the US on these issues. :-) But we drifting from language to religion and politics, so I'll stop here before the whole thread gets deleted as off topic.

Comment: @Jay: My bad, yes. But I think so long as we can avoid being "confrontational", it's not *entirely* OT to explore such matters in comments. Specifically, I'm thinking that *on average* there really is a difference in how "metaphoric" use of ***evangelical*** is likely to be perceived on both sides of the pond. So although it seems to me most Brits today would assume negative associations (or at least, an element of "poking fun" at zealotry in general) in most contexts, I'm quite prepared to believe that not only you, but *most* Americans, would consider it to be a pretty neutral word.

Comment: "Evangelist" is a common job title in high-tech industries in the USA and some other countries, with no religious overtones. Google "evangelist jobs" for examples.

Comment: There is a deep rooted difference between the UK and the US here. The US constitution formally separates religion from government, which is presumably why political candidates devote so much effort in their campaigns to appeal to identifiable religious groups. On the other hand, in the UK the monarch is by definition the head of the established church, and any connection between politics and religion is largely irrelevant (except for small pressure groups who want to exclude Church of England bishops from the House of Lords, and suchlike). Go figure!

Comment: @alephzero: I've no idea whether the Queen really *does* believe in (a) god, and to be honest I think it's no more a matter of legitimate "public interest" than wanting to know details about her sexual proclivities. But it's worth noting that her hopeful successor Prince Charles wants to be known as *Defender of Faith* (***without*** the article which would unambiguously imply ***the Christian** faith*). Which superficially seems laudably "inclusive", but doesn't really appeal to me.

Answer (score 10):

"Missionary" is generally used to mean someone who has made converting others to his religion his life's work. The usual connotation is that this is his job: he is supported by a church or missionary organization or some form of contributions from others. If he does have a regular job to support himself, he views this as secondary: his job is a means to support his mission work, and not something he does for itself. (Missionaries who support themselves are often called "bivocational missionaries".

"Evangelist" is very similar in meaning to "missionary". In Christian circles, I think the word "missionary" is used for people who go to a foreign country or another culture, while "evangelist" is used for those who try to spread the faith at home. Like speaking as someone from the U.S., a person who toured the U.S. preaching Christianity would be called an "evangelist", while someone who went to Kazakhstan to spread Christianity would be called a "missionary".

"Proselytize" is a verb meaning to try to convert others to your religion. The dictionary gives "proselytizer" as the noun form, but I think that's very rarely used. "Proselytize" tends to have negative connotations. If you resent someone else trying to convince you to change your religion, you might say "he's trying to proselytize me". But a religious group would be unlikely to say, "Hey, let's go out and try to proselytize a bunch of people".

In conservative Christian circles, it's common to refer to people trying to convert others to Christianity as "witnessing", and to a person who engages in such efforts as "a witness". As in, "Bob is trying to be a witness at his job", meaning, Bob is trying to talk about Christianity and convert others at his job. I've never heard this term used for other religions: I don't think anyone talks about a "Muslim witness" or a "Buddhist witness" in this sense.

There's also the general word "preacher". A "preacher" might be trying to convert people. But he also might be trying to teach people who already share his faith more about that faith, or encourage them to practice it more faithfully, etc.

Anyone who talks a lot about his faith might be called an "outspoken X", that is, an "outspoken Christian", "outspoken Muslim", etc.

Comment: Literally a "missionary" is someone who is sent. Broadly all missionaries are evangelists, but not all evangelists are missionaries. Both terms are traditionally exclusively Christian. All (Christian) preachers would also be evangelists, as they are spreading the Good News. None of the terms imply a specific intent to convert - only to teach/inform.

Comment: I think proselyte and related terms are traditionally only associated with Judaism (which doesn't actively seek converts, and is historically viewed negatively), being the only other religion English-speakers would largely come into contact with, and we already had the Christian-specific words.

Comment: @OrangeDog I agree with your evangelist/missionary distinction. I don't think "missionary" is exclusively Christian: people talk about "Muslim missionaries" and "Buddhist missionaries". Evangelist comes from the Greek for "tell the good news", "good news" being the Gospels, so I don't think it's strictly applicable to other religions, but if you talked about a "Buddhist evangelist", people would surely know what you meant.